# How to upload multiple image to cloudinary by Spring?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, file-upload, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload 3 image to Cloudinary and insert their link in SQL Server, but my code still add 1 link because I set same link. So my question is what solution to set each image link for each image file. My code below.

```
 <body>
<form:form  action="addR" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="room">
    <div>
        <form:label path="roomTypeID">Room type :</form:label> <select style="width:100px; height: 30px;">
            <c:forEach items="${dataRT}" var="rt">
                <option value="${rt.idRoomType}">${rt.nameRoomType}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="roomName">Room Name: </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="roomName"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="price">Price</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="price"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="description">Description</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="description"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="benefits">Benefits</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="benefits"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="area">Area</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="area"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="bed">Beds</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="bed"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="adults">Adults</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="adults"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="children">Children</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="children"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="roomUrl1">Image 1</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input type="file" path="file"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="roomUrl2">Image 2</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input type="file"  path="file"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="roomUrl3">Image 3</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input type="file" path="file"/></td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
    <div>
        <form:button type="submit">Add</form:button>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

@Table(name = "Room")

@Entity(name = "RoomEntity")

@NoArgsConstructor

@Getter

@Setter

@AllArgsConstructor

public class Room implements Serializable {

```
@Id

@GeneratedValue(generator = "my_generator2")

@GenericGenerator(name = "my_generator2", strategy = "Finalproject.spring.mvc.MyGenerator.GenerationRID")

@Column(name = "RoomID", columnDefinition = "varchar(10)")
private String id;

@Column(name = "RoomTypeID", columnDefinition = "varchar(10)")
private String roomTypeID;

@Column(name = "RoomName", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(50)", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String roomName;

@Column(name = "Price", columnDefinition = "float")
private float price;

@Column(name = "Description", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(max)")
private String description;

@Column(name = "Benefits", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(max)")
private String benefits;

@Column(name = "Area", columnDefinition = "float")
private float area;

@Column(name = "Bed", columnDefinition = "int")
private int bed;

@Column(name = "Adults", columnDefinition = "int")
private int adults;

@Column(name = "Children", columnDefinition = "int")
private int children;

@Column(name = "RoomUrl", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(max)")
private String roomUrl1;

@Column(name = "RoomUr2", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(max)")
private String roomUrl2;

@Column(name = "RoomUr3", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(max)")
private String roomUrl3;

@Column(name = "IsRent", columnDefinition = "bit")
private boolean isRent;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "RoomTypeID"/* , referencedColumnName = "" */, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private RoomType roomTypeId;
@Transient
private MultipartFile file;
```

}

```
public class RoomServiceImpl implements RoomService {
@Autowired
private RoomRepository roomRepository;
@Autowired
private Cloudinary cloudinary;

@Override
public boolean addRoom(Room room) {
    try {
        Map r = this.cloudinary.uploader().upload(room.getFile().getBytes(),
                ObjectUtils.asMap("resource_type", "auto"));
        room.setRoomUrl1((String) r.get("secure_url"));
        room.setRoomUrl2((String) r.get("secure_url"));
        room.setRoomUrl3((String) r.get("secure_url"));
        room.setRent(false);
        return this.roomRepository.addRoom(room);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("add image" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloudinary SDKs only accept one file at a time for upload. In your case, you have to call the upload method thrice to obtain three different URLs.

Sample code:

```
public class RoomServiceImpl implements RoomService {
@Autowired
private RoomRepository roomRepository;
@Autowired
private Cloudinary cloudinary;

    @Override
    public boolean addRoom(Room room) {
        try {
            room.setRoomUrl1((String) upload(room).get("secure_url"));
            room.setRoomUrl2((String) upload(room).get("secure_url"));
            room.setRoomUrl3((String) upload(room).get("secure_url"));
            room.setRent(false);
            return this.roomRepository.addRoom(room);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("add image" + e.getMessage());
        }
    return false;
    }
    
    private Map upload(Room room){
        Map r = this.cloudinary.uploader().upload(room.getFile().getBytes(),
                ObjectUtils.asMap("resource_type", "auto"));
        return r;
    }

}
```